# Replacing two divs without having bottom content flicker during the replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with very similar content.
When the button is clicked, I would like the first div to disappear and the second one to appear in the exact same place.
They do not have a constant height, but they should have the same automatic height because they have very similar content.

I implemented this example to demonstrate the problem.
In this snippet, you can see that once the button is clicked, the divs are replaced with a fade in/out animation.
The problem is that the content below (`text text` in this example), goes up and down during the fade in / out process, which impacts negatively on user experience.

Assuming there is a lot of content below these divs, it just doesn't look good.

What would be the best way to implement this behavior without having all content below the divs "flicker" during the replacement?

```js
$("#clicker").click(function() {
  if ($('.first').is(':visible')) {
    $('.first').fadeOut();
    $('.second').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.second').fadeOut();
    $('.first').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="clicker">Click me</button>

<div style="background-color:yellow;display:none" class="first">first content</div>
<div style="background-color:red" class="second">second content</div>

<div id="more_stuff_here">
  text text<br> text text
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have applied `fade` effect for both `display:none` and `display:block`. So it will disturb your layout because at some point of animation both elements are becoming `display:block`.

So the solution is there is no need of fade effect when you are doing `display:none`. Just use `hide()`.

So use `hide()` instead of `fadeOut()`. `fadeIn()` will animate your content.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$("#clicker").click(function() {
  if ($('.first').is(':visible')) {
    $('.first').hide();
    $('.second').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.second').hide();
    $('.first').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="clicker">Click me</button>
<div style="background-color:yellow;display:none" class="first">first content</div>
<div style="background-color:red" class="second">second content</div>
<div id="more_stuff_here">
  text text<br> text text
</div>
```

Comment: Can't see why this was down-voted (I up-voted and accepted the answer).

Comment: @TomShir I think someone is just playing with buttons as he/she down-voted all the answers...:)

Comment: My answer got downvoted too lol. But I think I deserve it for not explaining my solution properly. xD

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#clicker").click( 
        function()
        {
            if ($('.first').is(':visible')) {
              $('.first').fadeOut();
              $('.second').fadeIn();
            }
            else {
              $('.second').fadeOut();
              $('.first').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    );
```

```css
.first, .second {
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="clicker">Click me</button>

<div style="background-color:yellow;display:none" class="first">
  first content
</div>

<div style="background-color:red" class="second">
  second content
</div>

<div id="more_stuff_here">
text text<br>
text text
</div>
```

Comment: @Tiba Do NOT alter other people's answers! Write your own answer and leave those of others alone.

Comment: @CindyMeister. I thought I can improve his answer by shortening his code. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer you to wrap .first and .second in a div with constant height.

```
<div class="container"><div class="first">....</div><div class="second">....</div></div>
```